# Virtual properties don't get populated when passing model from view to controller

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

When I run the program and set a breakpoint in the controller method, I can step through and see that recipe.Name and recipe.ID are properly populated, but recipe.Ingredients is empty.

What am I overlooking? Here is my relevant code:

Model:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Cookbook.Models.Recipe
// removed irrelevant code for this question
<dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</dt>
<dd>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</dd>
<dd>
   <table class="table">
        <tr><th>Ingredient</th></tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Ingredients)
        {
            <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)</td></tr>
        }
    </table>
</dd>
<p> @Html.ActionLink("Export Data", "ExportData", Model)</p>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ExportData (Recipe recipe)
{
    //I am dynamically building an XML file by constructing it line by line
    string xml = recipe.Name + "\r\n\r\n"; //Here, Name is populated
    //Here, recipe.Ingredients is empty even though it appears in the view
    foreach(Ingredient ing in recipe.Ingredients)
    {
        xml = xml + ing.Ingredient.Name + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot pass a model containing a collection of complex objects to a GET method. Look at the `href` attribute of your link to understand

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you! What is the best practice way of retrieving this data then? Make a separate call to the database from my controller to query the data I need?

Comment: Yes, just pass the ID of the model to the `ExportData` method and get the data you need from your repository.

Comment: Okay, cool. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a model containing a property which is a collection (or a complex object) to a get method using `@Html.ActionLink()`. Internally the method generates the query string values by calling the `.ToString()` method on each property in the model. In your case it is generating

```
...?ID=someValue&Name=someValue&Ingredients=System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Ingredient>
```

In order to bind to you model it would need to be

```
...?....&Ingredients[0].Name=someValue&Ingredients[1].Name=someValue&...
```

Instead. pass the ID of the model to the method and then get the model again (as you did in the GET method which generated this view) to build you xml file

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export Data", "ExportData", new { id = Model.ID })

public ActionResult ExportData (int ID)
{
  var recipe = db.Recipies.Where(r => r.ID = ID).FirstOrDefault();
  ....
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help.